# <= && >= Java/Android Operators

Tags: java, android

Im having a problem on this block of code. It always go on the "You're outside of the museum or Check your position again" toast :/ what do you think is the problem? Here is the code:

```
    x3 = x3 * -1; //for example is 187
    y3 = y3 * -1;//for example is 698

    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    if(((x3 <= 150) && (x3 >= 170)) && ((y3 <= 680) && (y3 >= 725))){
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.map_1_full_lite);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You're currently on Section 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        currentSection = "sect_1";
    }else if(((x3 <= 170) && (x3 >= 195)) && ((y3 <= 690) && (y3 >= 715))){
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.map_2_full_lite);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You're currently on Section 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //this suppost to be the output
        currentSection = "sect_2";
    }else if(((x3 <= 200) && (x3 >= 230)) && ((y3 <= 680) && (y3 >= 720))){
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.map_3_full_lite);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You're currently on Section 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        currentSection = "sect_3";
    }else if(((x3 <= 190) && (x3 >= 220)) && ((y3 <= 675) && (y3 >= 710))){
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.map_4_full_lite);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You're currently on Section 4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        currentSection = "sect_4";
    }else if(((x3 <= 175) && (x3 >= 219)) && ((y3 <= 710) && (y3 >= 745))){
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.map_5_full_lite);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You're currently on Section 5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        currentSection = "sect_5";
    }else if(((x3 <= 155) && (x3 >= 165)) && ((y3 <= 715) && (y3 >= 735))){
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.map_6_full_lite);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You're currently on Section 6", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        currentSection = "sect_6";
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You're outside of the museum or Check your postion again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: x3 cannot be both less than 150 and greater than 170 simultaneously.

Comment: I would also like to mention that the program doesn't say "You're outside of the museum or Check your position again", ever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible

```
(x3 <= 150) && (x3 >= 170)
```

as is

```
(x3 <= 170) && (x3 >= 195)
```

x3 cannot be less than or equal to 150 AND greater than or equal to 170.  I suspect you intended something like this

```
(150 <= x3) && (x3 <= 170)
```

and

```
(170 <= x3) && (x3 <= 195)
```

Comment: You mean || in your last statement, didn't you?

Comment: Corrected it. I meant `x3` is between [150, 170] I assume he has tiles the user can click on.

Comment: the logic is that if the x3 = 187(for example) is between of 150 x to 170 x and y3 = 693(for example) is between of 690 y and 715 y, then that coordinate is on that section.. something like that :O

Comment: How is 187 between 150 and 170?

Comment: I would write this as `150 <= x3 && x3 <= 170 && 680 <= y3 && y3 <= 725`

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the help, i just reverse the operator from <= to >= and >= to <= lol... that code became ok.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your statements such as

```
(x3 <= 150) && (x3 >= 170)
```

can never be true.

Did you mean this?

```
(x3 <= 150) || (x3 >= 170)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have conditions that are always `false`. Just consider:

```
((x3 <= 155) && (x3 >= 165)) && ((y3 <= 715) && (y3 >= 735))
```

the `&&` operator is `AND` meaning both of the conditions on the sides of that operator must be true for the whole expression to be true. Now it is not hard to find out that for *any* value of `x3` the condition `(x3 <= 155) && (x3 >= 165)` is false. Thus the condition can never be met.

Every branch of your `if` has that property, so in the end the `else` branch is chosen.

I think you have mixed the `<=` (less than or equal) and `>=` (more than or equal) operators. All the values, for example `x3`, should be in some range (i.e. room boundary coordinates), like in the mentioned case `x3` should probably be in the range `(x3 >= 155) && (x3 <= 165)` (note reversed operators).